# Mockery. Check parameter on the 100-th call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, mockery, laravel-testing

I'm using `Mockery` with `Laravel 5.6`. And currently I need to check what has been passed on the 100-th call.

Here is an example check, that I want to perform.

```
Mockery::mock(ShopifySDK::class)
       ->shouldReceive('get')
       ->with(['key' => 'val']) //I need to check passed array on the 100-th call of the "get" method
       ->getMock();
```

Is it possible to do it? If it is, then how to do it?

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900843/how-to-throw-an-exception-on-the-nth-call-of-a-mock-method-with-mockery may help, but worth a try.

Comment: @NigelRen looks like, but is there any other...more "native" way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NigelRen 
This is the solution I found. A little bit ugly, but good enough for me.

```
Mockery::mock(ShopifySDK::class)
       ->shouldReceive('get')
       ->withArgs(function ($params) {
           static $counter = 0;

           if ($counter++ === 100) {
               //checks...

               return true;
           }

           return false;
       })->getMock();
```